# Unable to find MSBuild 15 while building a C# project, Unable to find "Microsoft.Common.props"

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm currently attempting to build a C# project, but MSBuild fails with:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props(33,11): error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found. Also, tried to find "15.0
\Microsoft.Common.props" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\MSBuild.d
ll.config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
```

My `.csproj` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>
    <AssemblyName>MyProj</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>MyProj</PackageId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: You've verified the files do exist in either of those locations?

Comment: The the latest version of Microsoft's Build Tools installer places MSBuild in a new location, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild`, instead of the normal `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild`. How do I configure the project to recognize that?

Comment: `"These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\MSBuild.dll.config"`

Comment: Is there not a way to configure it in the project, rather than manually modifying a build tool on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while using Visual code installed in CentOS. I tried everything but issue wasn't fixing out. What I did just located the my dotnet `sdk path` and then try to find **"Microsoft.Common.Props"** within the folder. In my case sdK folder was:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk
```

And surprisingly, I found this file within `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.203/Current` folder instead of /usr/share/dotnet/sdk//2.2.203/15.0/. So, what I did is just copying and pasted the file to the /`usr/share/dotnet/sdk//2.2.203/15.0/` location and problem was gone immediately!